# Unity3D JSON Deserializing Empty List?

Tags: json, unity-game-engine

I have a web service that returns an empty list (just `[]`).

`JsonUtility.FromJson` is giving me an

> ArgumentException: JSON must represent an object type.

I have isolated this down to a bit of code as simple as:

```
string empty = "[]";
FriendManager.FriendList test = JsonUtility.FromJson<FriendManager.FriendList>(empty);
Assert.IsNotNull(test);
```

`FriendList` is just a wrapper for `Friend[]`.  I also tried `List<Friend>`:

```
string empty = "[]";
FriendManager.FriendList test = JsonUtility.FromJson<List<Friend>>(empty);
Assert.IsNotNull(test);
```

Am I missing something obvious?

I have control over the server data (Spring Boot JSON web service) and the client (Unity3D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/jsonutility-json-must-represent-an-object-type.376403/)

> You can't use JsonUtility with a type like List directly, you have to use it with a defined class or struct type

so your second attempt will not work. And you also cannot directly asign it to `FriendManager.FriendList` if it s of type `List<Friend>` as you said.

You rather need a wrapper class for it like e.g.

```
[Serializable]
public class FriendList
{
    public List<Friend> Friends = new List<Friend>();
}
```

make `FriendManaget.FriendList` of type `FriendList`

And than either the server or you have to append the field name to that array namely the name of the variable: `Friends` e.g. like

```
FriendManager.FriendList test = JsonUtility.FromJson<List<Friend>>("\"Friends\":" + empty);
```

or the server has to send

```
"Friends":[]
```

Comment: Yup, that was it - thanks!  I wound up changing the server implementation - want it to be as friendly as possible for Unity3D.