# How do I organize the data of a json obtained from a server?

Tags: c, json, sql-server

I'm making an application in unity that connects to a database and I need to organize the information obtained from it, I use the following coruotine to get the information:

```
private IEnumerator GetUsers(string url)
{

    using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
    {
        // Request and wait for the desired page.
        yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

        if (webRequest.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.Log(": Error: " + webRequest.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.log("DATA:\n" + webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
        }
    }
}
```

and then I would like the data I receive (names, surnames, code, password ... etc) to organize it to print them or to later use them depending on what I need, thank you very much in advance.

and tried to use a serializable class to save my data but I only work with one (and when with my own data not from the server lol),I have also tried to make a vector of type people to save more than one data and it did not work either
:C or rather I did not know how to make it work

```
[System.Serializable]
public class People 
{
    public string names, surnames, cedula, password, telephone, address, code, 
    email;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class PeopleList
{
    public People[] users;
}
public class GetSendDate : MonoBehaviour
{
   private IEnumerator GetUsers(string url)
    {

        using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
        {
            // Request and wait for the desired page.
            yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

            if (webRequest.isNetworkError)
            {
                Debug.Log(": Error: " + webRequest.error);
            }
            else
            {
                PeopleList users = new People();

                string json = webRequest.downloadHandler.text;

                users = JsonUtility.FromJson<PeopleList>(json);

                Debug.Log(users.user[0].names);
                Debug.Log(users.user[0].surnames);
                Debug.Log(users.user[0].cod);

             }
        }
  }
}
```

this is the response of webRequest.downloadHandler.text

```
[{"userID": 1, "idRole": 1, "email": "ada@gmail.com", "password": "$ 2a $ 10 $ YVXachXCaPBj9vDo.d4itO4vghtCvSMfrmeHCGJqJ6rSneM / hJsPy", "names": "Juanota Rosadita" , "surnames": "sapoton", "cedula": "123", "telefono": "789", "direccion": "147", "code": "258"}, {"idUsuario": 7, " idRole ": 1," email ":" vic@gmail.com "," password ":" $ 2a $ 10 $ JA1rszAgVK52OnWoOWDXneQcVUHwWBi2Di9o2z7kMqrWPyrjGoTnO "," names ":" victor "," Surnames ":" giron "," cedula ":" 1085 "," telefono ":" 313 "," direccion ":" yoquese "," code ":" 217 "}, {" idUsuario ": 8," idRole ": 1," email ":" juanos @ gmail. com "," password ":" $ 2a $ 10 $ 6EAy2e7dXASx2MPDA3vtW.heYuM1wsaEtFmA4Lb6BD0RCTJvm / HSe "," names ":" Juanito "," Surnames ":" Alcachofa "," cedula ":" 789 "," telefono ":" 31358964 " , "address": "123", "code": "753"}]
```

I get the following error when I run the function in unity:

> ArgumentException: JSON must represent an object type.
>   UnityEngine.JsonUtility.FromJson (System.String json, System.Type type) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/JSONSerialize/Public/JsonUtility.bindings.cs:42)
>   UnityEngine.JsonUtility.FromJson[T] (System.String json) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/JSONSerialize/Public/JsonUtility.bindings.cs:30)
>   GetSendDate+d__6.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/GetSendDate.cs:73)
>   UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Scripting/Coroutines.cs:17)

Comment: sounds like you haven't researched enought. Google the exception and debug the code to understand it further

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity3D JSON Deserializing Empty List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53715617/unity3d-json-deserializing-empty-list)

Answer (score 0):

Can you send a capture "Debug.log" of your response `webRequest.downloadHandler.text`?

Because it is very likely that you are trying to transform the entire response, including the header. you only have to transform the response data to json.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Newton Soft Json Utility for parsing.

Just download DLL file and put it in your Assets/Plugins folders
You can download from:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Newtonsoft.Json/

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

private IEnumerator GetUsers(string url)
    {

 using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
        {

        yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

            if (webRequest.isNetworkError)
            {
                Debug.Log(": Error: " + webRequest.error);
            }
             else if (m_Request.isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.Log(" Server Not Responding ");
            }
            else
            {
                var response = JObject.Parse(m_Request.downloadHandler.text);
                users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PeopleList>(response.SelectToken("data"))
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If not then just try Parsing Only data Token as you're parsing complete string